# PHP checking XenForo user's account data

Tags: php, api, xenforo

I am authenticating XenForo user via php.

My code:

```
public function Auth($username, $password)
{
    $userIDA = $this->getarray("SELECT * FROM xf_user WHERE username='".$username."'");

    if($userIDA) 
    {
        define('SESSION_BYPASS', false); // if true: logged in user info and sessions are not needed
        require_once('library/XenForo/Autoloader.php');

        $AutoLoader = XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $AutoLoader->setupAutoloader('library');
        XenForo_Application::initialize('library', '');
        XenForo_Application::set('page_start_time', microtime(true));
        XenForo_Application::disablePhpErrorHandler(); //
        XenForo_Session::startPublicSession(); //
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE); // Turn off the strict error reporting.

        $db = XenForo_Application::get('db');
        $result = $db->fetchCol('SELECT user_id FROM xf_user WHERE username='.$db->quote($username));
        $user_id = $result[0];
        $result = $db->fetchCol('SELECT data FROM xf_user_authenticate WHERE user_id='.$db->quote($user_id));
        $data = $result[0]; 

        $auth = NULL;

        if(class_exists('XenForo_Authentication_Core12'))
            $auth = new XenForo_Authentication_Core12;
        else if(class_exists('XenForo_Authentication_Core'))
            $auth = new XenForo_Authentication_Core;

        $auth->setData($data); 

        if ($auth->authenticate($user_id, $password))
        {
            switch (intval($user_id))
            {
                default: 
                    return 1; 
                break;
                case 1:
                    return -1; 
                case 3:
                    return -1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return 2;
    }
    else return 3;
}
```

error log:

[12-Aug-2017 20:08:45 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class XenForo_Autoloader in /home/*******/*******/library/XenForo/Autoloader.php on line 16

So, please help me, what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code instead,

XenForo_Autoloader::getInstance()->setupAutoloader($forum_directory . '/library');